# How i can close all parents and classes in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make this code close all windows which are opened on windows class. At this moment it only closes few of them. Code works perfectly, but it just dont remove all windows which needs to be removed. Can someone please help me to make this script working?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import webbrowser
import time
import random

def closeall():
    global close
    close = True
    self = selfstr
    parent = parentstr
    Window.__init__(self, parent)

class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        if close == True:
            self.destroy()
        else:
            global selfstr
            selfstr = self
            global parentstr
            parentstr = parent
            
            plusminus_list = ["+", "-"]
            plusminus = random.choice(plusminus_list)
            plusminus2 = random.choice(plusminus_list)
            location = random.randint(1, 1000)
            location2 = random.randint(1, 1000)
        
            super().__init__(parent)

            self.geometry(f'256x256{plusminus}{location}{plusminus2}{location2}')
            self.title('NOESCAPE')

            frame = Frame(self, width=256, height=256)
            frame.pack()
            frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.5)

            img_list = ["jeff2", "jeff3", "jeff4", "jeff5", "jeff6"]
            randomimg = random.choice(img_list)
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f"{randomimg}.jpg"))

            label = Label(frame, image = img)
            label.pack()

            def on_closing():
                plusminus_list = ["+", "-"]
                onlywayout()
            
                plusminus = random.choice(plusminus_list)
                plusminus2 = random.choice(plusminus_list)
                location = random.randint(1, 1000)
                location2 = random.randint(1, 1000)
                img_list = ["jeff2", "jeff3", "jeff4", "jeff5", "jeff6"]
                randomimg = random.choice(img_list)
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f"{randomimg}.jpg"))
                Window(self)

            self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
            self.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

So you cannot access all Window instances you created for some reason? Then you could save a list with all instances in the Window class as a class attribute. With this list you should be able to destroy all Window instances. Your approach with using the constructor and global variables is a very bad coding style and you shouldn't do anything like this.

Here I created a classmethod so that you don't need the extra function closeall():

```py
import tkinter

class Window(tkinter.Toplevel):
    instances = []  # class attribute

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.instances.append(self)  # save current instance to the list

        # ...

    @classmethod
    def destroy_all_instances(cls):
        for window in cls.instances:
            window.destroy()


# Destroy all Window instances:
Window.destroy_all_instances()
```

Comment: Hey! How I can call the "Window.__init__()" function, like I have to put some kind of self and parent there. I just don't know how to do it. Here is the code that I'm trying to call.

`class Window(tk.Toplevel):

    instances = []
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        if close == True:
            destroy_all_instances(cls)
        else:
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.instances.append(self)`

Comment: I don't know what you want, but what I can say is you don't use the `__init__` constructor method to destroy your instance, that's one of the worst things you can do in terms of coding style!!!

Comment: Okay what kind of constructor method you prefer?

Comment: Do you mean destructor?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Okay you don't need a destructor in your case. If you want to delete an object you just do `del <object>`. But what exactly is not working with my code example above, does it not destroy all windows? `window.destroy()` is some kind of destructor because it destroys the window...

Comment: Yes but I want call the __init__(self, parent) function. Is it possible?

Comment: Where you want to call it and why? You never call the `__init__` function unless you inherit from something and then you do `super().__init__()`

Comment: I want call
        @classmethod
        def destroy_all_instances(cls):

When im trying to call it with "destroy_all_instances(cls)" 

It says: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'destroy_all_instances' referenced before assignment

Comment: You do it like this: `Window.destroy_all_instances()` as I wrote above. You call the function `destroy_all_instances` on the class `Window` itself, because its a class method, so you don't call it on a specific object.

Comment: Okay now it almost works. It says "NameError: name 'cls' is not defined"

Comment: I cannot know where the error comes from when I don't see your code, but I would say just do it exactly like my code above and i ´t will work.